Which ladder do I need to comfortably clean gutters and solar panels on a 21ft 2-story home?
I measured distance from ground the the beginning of the roof as 21ft. Roof has 30degree pitch, so if my upper body extends beyond that 21ft roof line I believe that should be fine. Also I’m a bit uncomfortable with heights (not not afraid).
Which ladder do I need to get for this? The ladders have height and reach and I’m not sure what is the right figure. Also the ladder won’t be straight but at an angle. How do I need to take this into account?

You add in a 30 to 40 % angle to the 21ft, so looking at minimum of 25ft or add in safety for 30ft ladder.  Using ladders should be done with friends not drinking beer, or anchored to the building(ropes/bolts).  As my dad said, it is not the fall, but the sudden stop that hurts.  Can also look into renting a small cherry picker/man lift.

Do find out the "working length" of the ladder, it should take a 32 ft ladder to do the task.  That way, it will not need to be extended out to its maximum.  https://www.wernerco.com/us/support/how-to-choose-a-ladder/ladder-height

As a solar panel owner (and cleaner), I'd hesitate to use the conventional tools available for swabbing a panel. I was able to find a long reach water-feed brush that allows me to stand on the ground. A second story would make that challenging, though, and performing the task on a ladder would terrify me.

@fred_dot_u Yes I'm getting these long reach water-feed brushes regardless, but for the ladder :) Indeed, no way from the ground works with my 21ft tall building. But I got the ladder already this afternoon and rinsed them with garden hose. Definitely need to get used to it but worked well.

Ladders should extend 3' above the edge and be 1 foot out for every 4 feet up. So sqrt(24^2+6^2) is about 25. In the real world, that means at least a 28' ladder. Suggest you don't get a flimsy one.

You do want to be on a solid base(ladder) when going up.  Even better is a solid base when coming down.

As a mention, a 28' ladder is made up of 2 -14 ft sections. The working length is much shorter, by about 4 ft or more, so in real time, it will only get to the roof edge, with only a little angle.

I got the Werner 28ft aluminium ladder from HD today and it worked well! Thanks for the advice. It's absolutely sufficient to stand next to the roof and clean the panels. But if needed, I think it's even sufficient to climb onto the roof.
